# semantic-ui menu dropdown not working

Tags: jquery, css, dropdown, semantic-ui

My semantic-ui menu dropdown isn't working. I've searched and searched and haven't found any solutions. Here's the menu code:

```
  <div class="ui fixed menu">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="/img/logo-black.png">
            </div>
            <div class="ui simple dropdown item">
                Dropdown <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                <div class="menu">
                    <a class="item" href="#">Link</a>
                    ..
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="item">Link</a>
            <a class="item">Link</a>
            <a class="item">Link</a>
            <div class="right menu">
                <a class="item">Sign Up</a>
                <a class="item">Login</a>
            </div>
```

And the script:

```
$('.ui.dropdown')
        .dropdown()
    ;
```

When I hover over the dropdown item it looks like its triggering an event but not actually showing the dropdown menu.

[Screenshot of my dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p84uD.jpg)

Comment: It's most likely a css issue and you have included no css in your question.

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle that demonstrates this issue.